# Xamarin ios simulator failed to install

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I try to run the application on ios I'm getting this error is occur. I'm windows user can anyone please help me

Please check following error

Failed to install

> //users/library/apple/cachee/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/project.ios/28dsdkjw323wm323dsddsdn232k23/bin/iphonesimulator/debug/project.ios.app
>   to DO3c105/Failed to lanuch this simulator

Comment: i am using visual studio 2019 and building a xamarin pcl project

Comment: Did you close remote simulator on windows? If you did, it probably can be caused it. You can try to restart windows. If it still doesn't work, you also can try on simulator Hardware - Erase all content and settings.

Comment: You may try to delete the cached files on you Mac. You may need to use the terminal for this. `rm -rf /users/library/apple/cachee/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/project.ios/`

Answer (score 0):

I would give you some suggestions:

1.Delete your `app` in the simulator, reset the simulator, delete the obj and bin folder, clean and rebuild the project again.

2.Restart your VS and try to update your Visual-Studio to the latest version.

3.Try the solution listed in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt1008-failed-to-launch-the-simulator):

**MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator**

> This error is reported if mtouch failed to launch the simulator. This
>   can happen sometimes because there is already a stale or dead
>   simulator process running.
>
> The following command issued on the Unix command line can be used to
>   kill stuck simulator processes:

```
$ launchctl list|grep UIKitApplication|awk '{print $3}'|xargs launchctl remove
```

Comment: OK, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is; (This assumes you have one project, if you have more then one you should be more careful with mass deleting, most likely below is a bit overkill)

1. Make sure you can see **hidden folders** and **library folders** on mac. If not search google for it.
2. Inside your mac, go to folder" /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Caches/Xamarin"
3. You will see bunch of folders like XMA, mtbs, Simulator
4. Delete all of them. This removes all your simulator apps, caches so system would recreate them.
5. (Optional) Clean Simulator content on macos. On simulator menu go to Device > Erase All Content and Settings...
6. Clean / Rebuild solution from Windows. You should see XMA folder recrated.
7. Run project on Windows on the selected simulator, this should re-create other folders and launch your app in simulator.